# Hilbert C*-Modules: Inner *-Isomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

*I have got a very basic question, but it would simplify some things, so I hope this resolves in either the affirmative or maybe someone can provide an I guess simple non-example.*

Given pairs of Hilbert C*-modules $X_1$ and $X_2$ over a common C*-algebra as well as $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ over a possibly different C*-algebra.
Suppose the adjointable operators of those pairs are *-isomorphic,
$$
\Phi:\mathcal{L}(X_1)\cong\mathcal{L}(X_2),\qquad\Psi:\mathcal{L}(Y_1)\cong\mathcal{L}(Y_2).
$$

My first question: Are the adjointable operators in between *-isomorphic,
$$
\mathcal{L}(X_1,Y_1)\cong\mathcal{L}(X_2,Y_2)?
$$

My second question: Are the inner *-homomorphisms
$$
\operatorname{ad}(R_1):\mathcal{L}(X_1)\to\mathcal{L}(Y_1):\quad\operatorname{ad}(R_1)(T_1):=R_1T_1R_1^*
$$
for isometries $R_1:X_1\to Y_1$,
in one-to-one correspondence via
$$
\operatorname{ad}(R_1)\mapsto\Psi\circ\operatorname{ad}(R_1)\circ\Phi^{-1}?
$$

Comment: If you allow different C$^*$-algebras, what kind of maps are $\Phi$ and $\Psi$? In a Hilbert C$^*$-module context I would expect those maps to preserve "scalar" multiplication.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: The idea I had in mind is to give a notion of innerness for $*$-homomorphisms $\varphi:A\to B$ for $A$ and $B$ arbitrary $C^*$-algebras by representing $A$ and $B$ faithfully as (sub-)$C^*$-algebras of adjointable operators. Existence of such faithful representations is clear while uniqueness is basically the question above.

Comment: Let me illustrate this at a motivating (and the leading) example:
Given $*$-homomorphisms $\varphi:A\to B$ for $A=M_2B$. Then we may represent them either as $*$-homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{K}_A(A)\to\mathbb{K}_B(B)$ (the canonical choice for $A$ and $B$) or alternatively as $*$-homomorphisms $\varphi:\mathbb{K}_B(B\oplus B)\to\mathbb{K}_B(B)$ (the "more" appropriate choice for $A=M_2B$).

Comment: As a consequence we obtain in the latter case: The inner $*$-homomorphisms become precisely pairs of isometries $u,v\in\mathcal{L}_B(B)=\mathcal{M}B$ and thus we recover as inner $*$-isomorphisms precisely the unital (embeddings) $\mathcal{O}_2\to\mathcal{M}B$. Moreover, these turn out to be precisely inner $*$-isomorphisms as defined by Thomsen between stable algebras in [Tho90]: These formalize the notion of Cuntz sums as in Ext-theory, bivariant K-theory, E-theory, Cuntz semigroups, and so on and so on.

Comment: Thus, an answer in the affirmative, in particular for the second question above, would allow for a notion of innernerss between different $C^*$-algebras as opposed to inner $*$-automorphims solely, and there seems to be evidence for its implementation in the study of topological groupoids (over non trivial unit space) and their induced groupoid $C^*$-algebras. Besides, (I didn't wanted to mention this in the question above) replacing isometries by arbitrary adjointably operators would yield a notion of inner cp-maps.

Comment: To answer your question: $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are $*$-homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras, and likely between adjointable operators of Hilbert modules over possibly different "scalars". As such, unitaries become senseless, so also adjunctions and so on. Thus, they possibly may not be induced via adjunction and to preserve scalar multiplication would become senseless as well. (Its basically a different categorical layer, in modern terms probably 2-arrows.)